# Adding Jar Plugins Dynamically, but issuing NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, dynamic, plugins, classloader

I am recently making a `PluginClassLoader` to load java plugins to my programs dynamically. So that the plugins can interacts with my program.

However, things won't go nicely though. So I looked up with bukkit's implementation of loading plugins. [[Bukkit's source code]](https://github.com/Bukkit/Bukkit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bukkit/plugin/java/PluginClassLoader.java) I followed with it, Java still throws me a `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Here's my implementation:

All the plugins that to be added are extended to `com.mob41.sakura.plugin.Plugin`. This abstract class contains `onCallPlugin()`, `onEndPlugin()`, etc. functions for the main program to interact to them. [[Abstract class source code]](https://github.com/mob41/Sakura/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mob41/sakura/plugin/Plugin.java)

All the plugins will be placed in a `/plugins` folder on the working directory (`System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\plugins"`). My program will find the folder (`/plugins`) on the working directory. If it doesn't exist, it creates a new folder. If exists, it will find all the `jar` files. And create a `PluginClassLoader` [[Source Code]](https://github.com/mob41/Sakura/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mob41/sakura/plugin/PluginClassLoader.java) to add the plugins.

I expected the plugins will be added to the my program and the classloader will create their instances. Through this testing code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Loading...");
    try {
        PluginManager.getPluginManager().loadAllPlugins();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("Loaded.");
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("ext", false);
    System.out.println((JSONObject) PluginManager.getPluginManager().runPluginLifeCycle("Sakura-Plugin-HKOWeather", json));
    }
```

If the plugin invalid/causes error when loading it, this [exception](https://github.com/mob41/Sakura/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mob41/sakura/plugin/exception/InvalidPluginException.java) will be thrown.
I don't know why my program cannot find the plugin that extended itself...

```
com.mob41.sakura.plugin.exception.InvalidPluginException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mob41/sakura/plugin/Plugin
    at com.mob41.sakura.plugin.PluginManager.loadPlugin(PluginManager.java:180)
    at com.mob41.sakura.plugin.PluginManager.loadAllPlugins(PluginManager.java:145)
    at com.mob41.sakura.Main.main(Main.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mob41/sakura/plugin/Plugin
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.mob41.sakura.plugin.PluginClassLoader.<init>(PluginClassLoader.java:25)
    at com.mob41.sakura.plugin.PluginManager.loadPlugin(PluginManager.java:176)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mob41.sakura.plugin.Plugin
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 17 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through hours of debugging, I finally found the answer.

I was specifying a wrong `ClassLoader` to my implementation of `PluginClassLoader`.